# Is it possible to force event listeners to fire in a particular order in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to be notified or perform some callback function once an event has finished propagating in JavaScript?

Equivalently, and more specifically: is there a way to 'prioritize' an event and make sure that it is called after every other event listener has been fired (similarly almost to the !important value in CSS).

For instance, if I have 3 event listeners - 2 attached to the window and 1 to some button element. Can I force a certain one of those events to be called LAST, regardless of where it lies in the DOM? I understand that there are event phases and the ability to attach a listener to the capture or bubbling phase but this still means there's a preset order.

edit: **the specific problem:**

I'm attempting to build components (in React JS) which are aware of a click being registered outside of themselves (i.e. anywhere on the window/document except themselves) - often as a way of closing/hiding the component. Each of these components will register a listener on the window object which fires a function belonging to that component.

The trouble is, when another component [B] (inherently lower down in the DOM than the window) is clicked to let's say toggle the display of [A], [B]'s event fires first and toggles the state 'showA', the event bubbles up and [A]'s window event listener kicks in and re-toggles the state 'showA' - so, [A] remains hidden after changing state twice. I can't use stopPropagation as other window events need to fire. I've tried to unbind listeners but this doesn't happen in time.

An example of what currently happens all in one go is:

- 'show thing' button clicked
- add listener to window for closing 'thing'
- 'window but not thing' was clicked
- remove listener to close 'thing'

**If only I could wait until the click event had finished bubbling before adding the new listener, I'd have no issue**

Comment: Yes, you can do callbacks in JavaScript.  Can you be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: Updated the question as it was way too vague @SurrealDreams

Comment: No. The best you'll get is to bind your listener at the root node, or use a timeout

Comment: What do you need this for? What problem do you try to solve?

Comment: @Bergi again, updated the q. This is fairly ReactJS specific I think...

Comment: I think your question could be solved by only binding the global click listener when A is shown. Also, if you want to catch clicks anywhere, like in a modal, wouldn't you rather create an overlay over the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

I did leave an answer to your original question but I see you've updated it. I wouldn't say this is React specific but a common implementation for components that need to close/de-activate when the document is clicked.

For instance, the following snippet is an implementation for a speed dial spin out button;

```js
(function () {
    var VISIBLE_CLASS = 'is-showing-options',
        btn  = document.getElementById('.btn'),
        ctn  = document.getElementById('.ctn'),
        showOpts = function(e) {
          var processClick = function (evt) {
            if (e !== evt) {
              ctn.classList.remove(VISIBLE_CLASS);
              ctn.IS_SHOWING = false;
              document.removeEventListener('click', processClick);
            }
          };
          if (!ctn.IS_SHOWING) {
            ctn.IS_SHOWING = true;
            ctn.classList.add(VISIBLE_CLASS);
            document.addEventListener('click', processClick);
          }
        };
    btn.addEventListener('click', showOpts);
}.call(this));
```

When the user clicks the button, the container is shown for the speed dial options and an event listener is bound to the document. However, you need to make sure that the initial event that is fired is not the one that triggers the takedown straight away (this is sometime a gotcha). This check is made with `if (e !== evt) ...`. For further clicks the event check is made and the relevant action taken ending in removal of the event listener from the document.

Of course in your particular case if you want to only close when the element isn't clicked then you could make relevant checks on the `evt.target` and `evt.currentTarget` in the callback (in the snippet case, `processClick`).

Hopefully, this can help you out with registering close down callbacks for your individual components.